# How to connect to zk ua300 using password with Connect_Net?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, biometrics, zkteco

I use VBA to communicate with ZK UA300 and everything is fine, but the problem is that anyone has the device's IP Add., can do anything they want to the device.
I do not want anyone to be able to connect to the devise except those who have the CommPassword.
I use the example below, but where in the code can I put the password?

So if I set the device's communication password, how will the code be?

`bconn = CZKEM1.Connect_Net(CStr(txtIP.value), CLng(txtPort.value))`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the method SetCommPassword before calling Connect_Net

```
CZKEM1.SetCommPassword(yourpassword)
bconn = CZKEM1.Connect_Net(CStr(txtIP.value), CLng(txtPort.value))
```